# Parsing file with python

Tags: python, regex, file, parsing

I'm trying to parse a file in python. I have a file like this:

```
ID number        Name
LOI_3456         Bacteria1       
HUI_6478         Bacteria1
PETY_3564        Bacteria1
```

So first I gathered all the ID_number per bacteria:

```
import re
f = open("file.tsv","r")
f.readline()
for line in f.readlines():
    line = li.rstrip("\n")
    line = li.rsplit("\t")
    ID_number = li[0]
```

Now in the other file, I have something like this:

```
d2234 d45564 d223098 d50923 PETY_354_d3456 d76533
d2635 PETY_354 d88593 d324623 HUI_6478_d3553d35626
...
```

Now I've got this in the same script:

```
   cnt = 0
    f2 = open("file2","r")
    for li in f2.readlines():
        li = li.rstrip("\n")
        pattern_id_number = re.search(ID_number+'_\d+', li)
        if pattern_id number in li:
           print("line :",n, li)
```

But that doesn't work. What I want is to keep the line which match with my pattern_id_member.

EDIT :

when I do :

```
if pattern_id :
   print(li)
```

instead of

```
if pattern_id in li:
   print(li)
```

Nothing is printed...

Comment: Use `if pattern_id_number:` instead of `if pattern_id number in li:`. Also, you may just use `for li in f2` to  iterate over the lines in `file2` file.

Comment: Are you saying that the ID number of first file will contain in the second file?

Comment: the Id_number of the first file is present on certain lines in file 2 but with an underscore juste after

Comment: Please pay attention: you use **`pattern_id_number`** in `pattern_id_number = re.search(ID_number+'_\d+', li)`, but then you check for **`pattern_id number`** in `if pattern_id number in li:`. See the typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is in the regex you construct here:

```
pattern_id_number = re.search(ID_number+'_\d+', li)
```

Tout `pattern_id_number` equals something like `HUI_6478` and when you add the `\d+` you get a regexp like:

```
HUI_6478_\d+
```

This regexp does not match anything in your second file.
I don't know the desired output, but it looks like you need to update the regexp creation to something like:

```
pattern_id_number = re.search(ID_number + '_\w\d+', li)
```

Then you will get an output:

```
line : d2635 PETY_354 d88593 d324623 HUI_6478_d3553d35626
```

EDIT: and yes, the above comments are also valid, you need to have

```
if pattern_id_number:
   print("line :", li)
```

Comment: Thank you ! It was so obvious…. sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import re
with open(r'C:\Users\widnows\Desktop\file1.csv', "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = [e[0].strip().split(",")[0] for e in reader if e]
your_list[1:]

>>['LOI_3456', 'HUI_6478', 'PETY_3564Bacteria1']

import string

s = s = '''d2234 d45564 d223098 d50923 PETY_354_d3456 d76533
d2635 PETY_354 d88593 d324623 HUI_6478_d3553d35626'''

result = re.findall('|'.join(your_list[1:]), s.translate({ord(c): None for c in string.whitespace}))
result
>>['HUI_6478']
```